# Disable Firebase data type messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase Console to send Data-type push notifications, it works good. 
But now i have a Terms and Conditions Activity, and i want to disable Firebase Services, if the user doesnt accepted the "Terms and Conditions" (its stored in Sharedpreferences, as boolean).

I found a solution on Stackoverflow, but it is not work for me, i get still the messages, if i send a notification from Firebase Console.

```
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseIntanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
    android:enabled="false">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a checkbox on your screen and set a condition on button click if the checkbox is checked then  go to the flow otherwise show the toast or a dialog box to user "you have to accept the terms and condition." like this:-

```
 if (land_chack.isChecked()) {
     // do your stuff here in accept your terms and conditions
     } else {
        Toast.makeText(LandingPage.this, "Please check terms and conditions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```